# Example of a universally injective ring morphism which is not faithfully flat

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

Is there some classic example of an universally injective ring morphism which is not a faithfully flat morphism?

I was not able to find it in any commutative algebra book and neither around here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, the classic way to obtain universally injective ring morphisms is to look for faithfully flat ring morphisms. I am asking if there is some example out of this.

Comment: What is the definition of "universally injective ring morphism"?

Comment: We say that a morphism of $R$-modules $f:M\rightarrow N$ is $R$-universally injective if $f\otimes_R 1_P: M\otimes_RP\rightarrow N\otimes_RP$ is injective, for any $R$-module $P$. In the ring case, a universally ring morphism $f:R\rightarrow S$ is that such the $\tilde{f}:P\rightarrow S\otimes_RP$ is injective, for any $R$-module $P$. It is easy to show that if $f$ is faithfully flat then $f$ is universally injective. I would like to find a counter-example of the converse, but I did not find anywhere, and I could not construct it by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example. Take a ring $R$ and a non-flat module $M$. Then, take $S=R\oplus M$ with the ring structure given by $M^2=0$. So, $(a,m)\cdot (b,n)=(ab, an+bm)$. Then the map $R\to S $ is split and thus universally injective. But $S$ is not flat over $R$.

Comment: Thanks @Mohan. It is really a nice example!